# AWK - My regexp won't respect case

Tags: ubuntu, awk, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, gawk

I'm running Ubuntu 8.04 and my code looks like this...

```
 for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {
  if (arr[i] ~ /^[A-Z]{2,4}$/) printf(arr[i])
 }
```

I quickly discovered that the {n} expression won't work in gawk without the --posix switch. Once enabled the expression works but it is case-insenitive matching AAAA and aaaa. What is going on here?

Comment: Show us the whole AWK script or command. I think I know what's going on, but you haven't provided enough info to be sure.

Answer (score 5):

The expression itself works for me:

```
dfs:~# gawk --posix '/^[A-Z]{2,4}$/ {print "Yes"}'
AAAA
Yes
AA
Yes
TT
Yes
tt
YY
Yes
yy
```

Your problems may be caused by two things. Either you accidentally set the `IGNORECASE` awk variable or otherwise turned of [case insensitive operation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Case_002dsensitivity) (BTW `IGNORECASE` doesn't work with `--posix`, but does with `--re-interval`, which enables the braces in regular expressions too), or it is a classic problem of locale's collating sequence (because gawk does locale aware character comparison), which means the lowercase characters compare between some uppercase characters. Quote from the [relevant part of the manual:](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Character-Lists)

> Many locales sort characters in
>   dictionary order, and in these
>   locales, ‘[a-dx-z]’ is typically not
>   equivalent to ‘[abcdxyz]’; instead it
>   might be equivalent to
>   ‘[aBbCcDdxXyYz]’, for example. To
>   obtain the traditional interpretation
>   of bracket expressions, you can use
>   the C locale by setting the LC_ALL
>   environment variable to the value ‘C’.

Comment: Perhaps you should specify that IGNORECASE is an environment variable for greater clarity.

Comment: Yes, I probably should have, because it in fact isn't an environment variable. Edited to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

I only have mawk installed, but maybe this is what your looking for?

for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
    if (arr[i] ~ [^A-Z]{2,4}$/) printf(arr[i])
 }

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this is what the OP asked for

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, if you're using ***GNU awk***, you could use the *[:upper:]* alphabetic character class.

```
% awk '{print /[:upper:]/?"OK":"KO"}'
AA
KO
aa
KO
```